# MYSQL statement, whats wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL query that fails.

```
SELECT `name`,`desc`,`address_line1`,`address_line2`,`address_line3`,`city`,`county`,`postcode`,`phone`,`website` `type` as `category`
FROM  `hw_services` 
JOIN `types`ON `types`.`ID` = `hw_services`.`type`
WHERE  `healthwatchID` = 54
```

I want to select the columns from hw_services but I want `type` to display as `category`.

Then the type field from `hw_services` relates to the ID in the `types` table.

Any ideas?

Comment: `'website' 'type' as 'category' ` comma is missing here

Comment: or if it is single column ``website type` as category`

Comment: Thanks guys, very silly mistake :)

Comment: You should define "fails" next time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the query. It is missing comma(,).

Corrected query:

```
SELECT 
`name`,`desc`,`address_line1`,`address_line2`,`address_line3`,`city`,`county`,`postcode`,`phone`,`website`, `type` as `category`
FROM  `hw_services` 
JOIN `types`ON `types`.`ID` = `hw_services`.`type`
WHERE  `healthwatchID` = 54
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a comma after 'website':

```
SELECT `name`,`desc`,`address_line1`,`address_line2`,`address_line3`,`city`,`county`,`postcode`,`phone`,`website` `type` as `category`
FROM  `hw_services` 
JOIN `types`ON `types`.`ID` = `hw_services`.`type`
 WHERE  `healthwatchID` = 54
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma after website.